# How to call a function containing chained promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I am chaining multiple asynchronous function calls using promises and the Q js library. My current code looks like this:

```js
    function user() {
      getID()
        .then(getName);
    }

    function getID() {
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      asyncCall(arg, function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      });
      return deffered.promise;
    }

    function getName(ID) {
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      asyncCall2(arg, function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      });
      return deffered.promise;
    }
```

I am trying to call user() from a different location and have it return the result of getName but am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just return the value (which is a promise itself):

```
function user() {
    return getID().then(getName);
}
```

and later you can use it as the rest of your code:

```
user().then(function(result) {});
```